# Multiple radio button groups in one form

Tags: html, forms, radio-group

Is it possible to have multiple radio button groups in a single form? Usually selecting one button deselects the previous, I just need to have one of a group deselected.

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="">
        <input type="radio" value="">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="">
        <input type="radio" value="">
        <input type="radio" value="">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Give them names (i.e. `<input type="checkbox" name="checkGroup1" value =""/>`

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Set equal `name` attributes to create a group;

```html
<form>
  <fieldset id="group1">
    <input type="radio" value="value1" name="group1">
    <input type="radio" value="value2" name="group1">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="group2">
    <input type="radio" value="value1" name="group2">
    <input type="radio" value="value2" name="group2">
    <input type="radio" value="value3" name="group2">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: if value equals "" every time, how do I know which radio button was chosen? how do I know if a radio button was chosen at all?

Comment: Insert your own values

Answer (score 20):

This is very simple you need to keep different names of every radio input group.

```html
      <input type="radio" name="price">Thousand<br>
      <input type="radio" name="price">Lakh<br>
      <input type="radio" name="price">Crore
      
      </br><hr>

      <input type="radio" name="gender">Male<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender">Female<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender">Other
```

Answer (score 15):

Just do one thing,
We need to set the name property for the same types. for eg.

**Try below:**

```
<form>
    <div id="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="val1" name="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="val2" name="group1">
    </div>
</form>
```

And **also we can do it in angular1,angular 2 or in jquery also.**

```
<div *ngFor="let option of question.options; index as j">
<input type="radio" name="option{{j}}" value="option{{j}}" (click)="checkAnswer(j+1)">{{option}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

in input field make name same 
like

```
<input type="radio" name="option" value="option1">
<input type="radio" name="option" value="option2" >
<input type="radio" name="option" value="option3" >
<input type="radio" name="option" value="option3" >
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Angular

For those ended up here having a similar issue with Angular, I fixed my problem by replacing the `[attr.name]` of the `<input>` with simply `[name]` which was the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To create a group of inputs you can create a custom html element

```
window.customElements.define('radio-group', RadioGroup);
```

https://gist.github.com/robdodson/85deb2f821f9beb2ed1ce049f6a6ed47

to keep selected option in each group, you need to add name attribute to inputs in group, if you not add it then all is one group.

Comment: Can you specify how this fixes the question's issue? This also creates just one group, does it add a unique name to the inputs of each group you create this way?