# Javascript User Input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create this script where the user can only select one option from category 1, one option from category 2, and the click submit to generate a link. 
What would be the best approach if I wanted this to live online and all be done client-side without the need for a server?
[image]

Comment: I'm brand new to this site, but I did upload a picture that I hope explains any questions.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a *"how to"* tutorial service

Comment: You should go to the help center and learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question on SO

Comment: Welcome to SO. A picture is not enough. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. For example search google for select unique

Comment: Search for onclick, class, querySelectorAll

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use radio buttons

```
<form>
    <fieldset id="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
        <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This answer is from here  [Multiple radio button groups in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543752/multiple-radio-button-groups-in-one-form)

If you edit the code a bit you get (You use value1 and value2 as strings for the link)

```
    <form>
        <fieldset id="group1" style="float:left;">
            <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
            <input type="radio" value="" name="group1">
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="group2" style="float:right;left:100px;">
            <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
            <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
            <input type="radio" value="" name="group2">
        </fieldset>
       <button onclick="myFunction();">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
value1 =document.getElementById('group1').value ;
value2 =document.getElementById('group2').value ;
}
</script>
```