# Handling multiple radio buttons in a Quiz Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, angular5, angular4-forms

I'm new to Angular and Implementing a Quiz containing multiple MCQs.
But I am having trouble in radio button selection.

My Questions are coming from the database and Options too.

**mcq.component.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="ff.form.valid && answer(ff)" #ff="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <p style="font-size: 25px;">{{question.title}}</p>
    <div *ngFor="let option of question.options">
        <input [(ngModel)]="option_model.selected_option_id" #selected_option_id="ngModel" type="radio" value="{{option.id}}" name="{{question.id}}">
        <!-- <input type="radio" value="{{option.id}}" name="{{question.id}}" ngModel > --> //This way it works fine but I need to use [(ngModel)] to submit the form
      {{option.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <input style="float: right" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Note:** The {{question.id}} is unique for each question. Also, this works well if I remove the [(ngModel)] attribute.

And here is what I'm trying to accomplish
[image: And here is what I'm trying to accomplish]

**The Problem:** When I select an option from the second question it deselects the selected option from the First Question. Means I am only able to select one option from both questions.

Please Help me, what I am doing wrong. I've been stuck here for two days.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple radio button groups in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543752/multiple-radio-button-groups-in-one-form)

Comment: Check if this  {{question.id}} is diffrent for all ques? Cause this can only happen if you have radio buttons with same name attribute for different questions.

Comment: Yes the {{question.id}} is different for both questions. This works when I remove [(ngModel)] attribute, But then I can't get the value when submitting form.

Comment: Seems some issue with the way you are using ngModel with radio buttons ! Share some fiddle where I can check whats the issue

Comment: I don't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Git it Sorted. The issue was with the ngModel and name attribute

It works fine like this

```
<input [(ngModel)]="options[question.id]" [checked]="options[question.id]" value="{{question.id}}-{{option.id}}" type="radio"
      name="option{{question.id}}">
```

And in typescript

```
options: any = [];
option: any = [];
```