# Is it possible to check multiple radio-buttons like this?

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I echo the value of the radio-buttons from my database and in this form       ( a while loop ) is the fastest way to get them. When I do this it sees all the radio-buttons as in the same "group". How do to make it so that it has multiple "groups" so it is possible to answer multiple questions?

I tried adding a div to it but that didn't work.

```
<form action="Antwoord.php" method="POST">
<?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM  questionlist_choice";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$vraag = $row['Vraag'];
$vraagA = $row['Vraag_keuzeA'];
$vraagB = $row['Vraag_keuzeB'];
$vraagC = $row['Vraag_keuzeC'];
$vraagD = $row['Vraag_keuzeD'];
$vraagE = $row['Vraag_keuzeE'];
$vraagF = $row['Vraag_keuzeF'];
echo "<div>";
    echo "<br><p>$vraag</p>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='gender' value='$vraagA'> $vraagA<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='gender' value='$vraagB'> $vraagB<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='gender' value='$vraagC'> $vraagC<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='gender' value='$vraagD'> $vraagD<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='gender' value='$vraagE'> $vraagE<br>";
    echo "<input type='radio' name='gender' value='$vraagF'> $vraagF<br>";
echo "</div>";



  }
}
?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I never mentioned checkboxes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple radio button groups in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543752/multiple-radio-button-groups-in-one-form)

Comment: if you need to group the radios give each group the same name: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio#Defining_a_radio_group

Comment: but this is from database and from a while loop so that would not work, or i would have to not do the whole loop. You can't name one thing in a loop.

Comment: Well then you need to think about what you are doing because that's how radio buttons work - eg put a counter in your while loop and append it to the name

Comment: usually you just use a grouping name to distinguish groups, but can you also add what kind of values you have inside your table in this post, maybe we would suggest a better answer

Comment: @Niels040 You have a static name in each radio button right now ('gender'). Just make sure that that name is variable per question and you're good.

Comment: i made each name different and when i checked it in a different question it went out in the first one.

Comment: I also did no name and then it works but I cant uncheck them and I can check them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't understand your question that much, but if you want to `GROUP` them you need to add index on `name` tag like this:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $vraag = $row['Vraag'];
   $vraagA = $row['Vraag_keuzeA'];
   $vraagB = $row['Vraag_keuzeB'];
   $vraagC = $row['Vraag_keuzeC'];
   $vraagD = $row['Vraag_keuzeD'];
   $vraagE = $row['Vraag_keuzeE'];
   $vraagF = $row['Vraag_keuzeF'];

   echo "<div>";
   echo "<br><p>$vraag</p>";
   echo "<input type='radio' name='gender[$i]' value='$vraagA'> $vraagA<br>";
   echo "<input type='radio' name='gender[$i]' value='$vraagB'> $vraagB<br>";
   echo "<input type='radio' name='gender[$i]' value='$vraagC'> $vraagC<br>";
   echo "<input type='radio' name='gender[$i]' value='$vraagD'> $vraagD<br>";
   echo "<input type='radio' name='gender[$i]' value='$vraagE'> $vraagE<br>";
   echo "<input type='radio' name='gender[$i]' value='$vraagF'> $vraagF<br>";
   echo "</div>";
$i++;
}
```

I use `$i` as the index, I think it would be better if you use `for loop` cause it already has `$key` value, I think using this in `while` is a bad habit.

Comment: How can i see the answers with the post on a other page i tried this: 
<html>
<body>

 <?php echo $_POST['[0]']; ?><br>
<?php echo $_POST['[1]']; ?>

</body>
</html>
But it doesn't work.

Comment: did you try `$_POST['gender[0]']`?

Comment: I removed Gender that was from w3schools XD

Comment: you need a name for it. a proper name not just an array

Comment: It is a  Undefined index according to the error message.

Comment: It's `$_POST['gender'][0]`