# boostrap5 radio button name group

Tags: radio-button, bootstrap-5, radio-group

First of all I should say that, I'm not native in English that may cause to misunderstanding on explanation.
I know that bootstrap 5 has [Radio button new styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#outlined-styles), but I need to have multiple groups of radio buttons on the view side.
(e.g.

```html
<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options-outlined" id="success-outlined" autocomplete="off" checked>
<label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="success-outlined">bootstrap radio1</label>
<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="options-outlined" id="success-outlined" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="success-outlined">bootstrap radio2</label>




<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="MyGroup name" id="success-outlined" autocomplete="off" checked>
<label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="success-outlined">My radio1</label>

<input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="MyGroup name" id="success-outlined" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-outline-success" for="success-outlined">My radio2</label>
```

)
As I can see in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396672/4754253 Grouping is working in simple radio without styles. but when I want to change the name property in bootstrap radio it does not work.
any suggestion on this subject is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Keep `name` attributes the same in a group, `id` should only occur once on the page.

Comment: That's absolutely right. It's working. My mistake was in naming characters , my name had space(' ') and I didn't pay attention. thanks you.