# How to make 5-star rating with CSS

Tags: html, css, input, label, pure-css

I've edited a version of CSS 5-star rating, and need **multiple of these ratings** on my one page. However, when I changed the id on the different sets of 5 stars, and now it won't process checking the stars.

I tried to have multiple sets of 5 stars, and edited IDs to do so, expecting it to work, but the stars would not receive checked value when checked.

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "★";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "★";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #ff0000;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #ff8080;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="1star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>

  <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="2star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="2starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour] , then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question about your code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is with the HTML.
Inputs have unique IDs but the `for` attribute in for each label **must be the same as the IDof the input it refers to** ([see the label element on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)).
Like this :

```css
fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "★";
}

.rating>.half:before {
  content: "★";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}

.rating>input:checked~label,

/* show gold star when clicked */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,

/* hover current star */

.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: #ff0000;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,

/* hover current star when changing rating */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,

/* lighten current selection */

.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  color: #ff8080;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="1star5" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="1star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="1star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="1star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="1star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="1star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="1star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="1star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="1star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="1star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="1starhalf" name="rating" value="half" />
  <label class="half" for="1starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="rating">
  <input type="radio" id="2star5" name="rating" value="5" />
  <label class="full" for="2star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="2star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star4" name="rating" value="4" />
  <label class="full" for="2star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="2star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star3" name="rating" value="3" />
  <label class="full" for="2star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="2star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star2" name="rating" value="2" />
  <label class="full" for="2star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" />
  <label class="half" for="2star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2star1" name="rating" value="1" />
  <label class="full" for="2star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2starhalf" name="rating" value="half" />
  <label class="half" for="2starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

*Note that you also didn't close the `<fieldset>` tags.*

Comment: Thank you, however in the code snippet and when used in my HTML file you can only keep the stars selected for one set of five at a time. Is there any way to fix this, or is it just a side effect of coding it this way?

Comment: @B___H___ it is a side effect of the technique used. To make several sets of seprate inputs type radio, you need to give the the same for attribute like in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543752/multiple-radio-button-groups-in-one-form . That won't be possible with your approach.